# Import a type family that is an operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, import, operators, type-families

`GHC.TypeNats` exports type family of the following signature:

```
type family (m :: Nat) + (n :: Nat) :: Nat
```

How can I import it explicitly? `import GHC.TypeNats((+))` does not work, because it says that `GHC.TypeNats` does not export `(+)`...

Everything compiles okay when I import whole module implicitly, but this really is not what I want to have in my code.

---

I am using GHC 8.6.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeOperators):

> There is now some potential ambiguity in import and export lists; for example if you write `import M( (+) )` do you mean the function `(+)` or the type constructor `(+)`? The default is the former, but with `ExplicitNamespaces` (which is implied by `TypeOperators`) GHC allows you to specify the latter by preceding it with the keyword type, thus:
>
> ```
> import M( type (+) )
> ```

Comment: How do you import `(*)` though? That is a parse error in GHC 9.0 it seems.

Comment: @Turion you have to set `{-# LANGUAGE NoStarIsType #-}` It took me a while to realize