# Import the * operator of type level naturals

Tags: haskell, import, type-level-computation

Follow-up to [Import a type family that is an operator in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58565505/import-a-type-family-that-is-an-operator-in-haskell).

This works:

```hs
import GHC.TypeLits (type (+))
```

This is a parse error in GHC 9.0:

```hs
import GHC.TypeLits (type (*))
```

See for example:

```
ghci -XTypeOperators
GHCi, version 9.0.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> import GHC.TypeLits (type (+))
ghci> import GHC.TypeLits (type (*))

<interactive>:2:28: error: parse error on input ‘*’
```

How do I import type level natural number multiplication?

Answer (score 3):

It is necessary to activate the language extension `NoStarIsType`, then it will work. Otherwise, `*` is going to be interpreted as `Type`.